# how to generalize hard coded loop

Tags: c#

Hi I am having hard time generalizing this hard coded loop. I have list  which contains codons (strings : AUG, CAG etc) for a peptide MW. M has codon AUG and W has codon UUG.

The purpose of the code is to combine the codons in the order MW: AUGUUG
the hardcoded loop gets it right. Here I know the number of amino acids in the given peptide (2 M and W) I want to generalize for any length of peptide MWMRS.....
specifically I have

```
aminoAcidCodons:{ Mcodons[AUG],Wcodons[UGG]}

for (int h = 0; h < aminoAcidCodons[0].Multiplicity; h++)
{
    stbld = new StringBuilder();
    stbld.Append(aminoAcidCodons[0].Codons[h]);
    codonsList0.Add(stbld.ToString());
    stbld.Clear();

    for (int j = 0; j < aminoAcidCodons[1].Multiplicity; j++)
    {
        stbld.Append(codonsList0[h]);
        codon = aminoAcidCodons[1].Codons[j];
        stbld.Append(codon);
        codonsList1.Add(stbld.ToString());
        stbld.Clear();
    }
}
```

I tried this generalized loop

```
for (int h = 0; h < aminoAcidCodons.Count ; h++)
{
    stbld = new StringBuilder();
    stbld.Append(aminoAcidCodons[h].Codons[0]);
    codonsList1.Add(stbld.ToString());
    stbld.Clear();

    for (int j = 0; j < aminoAcidCodons[h].Multiplicity; j++)
    {
        // stbld = new StringBuilder();
        // stbld.Append(aminoAcidCodons[h].Codons[0]);
        // codonsList0.Add(stbld.ToString());

        stbld.Append(codonsList1[h]);
        codon = aminoAcidCodons[h].Codons[j];
        stbld.Append(codon);
        codonsList1.Add(stbld.ToString());

        stbld.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Do you mean that you want to build your strings for any number of `aminoAcidCodons[n]`?

Comment: Possibly **unclear what you are asking**.  _"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question."_

Comment: I want something like this:

Comment: Seems like you could have multiple codons for a peptide.. How are you supposed to deal with it then? What would the result look like, if peptide M had multiple codons, and W had multiple codons.. If I don't make any sense (I do not have any understanding of genetics), it's just because I am trying to understand the way your current code looks to me.

Comment: thanks look again to edited post; yes they can have multiple codons and the hard coded loop works fine with multiple codons and any number of peptide length ie MWRS

Comment: It's difficult to understand your question with so many specialized properties and no type declarations shown. For example, what's the difference between `aminoAcidCodons[h].Multiplicity` and `aminoAcidCodons[h].Codons.Count`? If there's no difference, what's the point of representing the same piece of information in two different places? More generally, the code example doesn't seem as simplified as it could be for the purpose of your question. It would be better for you to express your basic question with as little domain-specific jargon as possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your edited question shows you adding the strings to one list only - `codonsList1` - but your original code shows strings being added to `codonsList0` & `codonsList1`. What do you want your generalised output to be?

Comment: Is there a difference between `aminoAcidCodons[h].Multiplicity` and `aminoAcidCodons[h].Codons.Count()`?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do in terms of _logic_, **not genetics** since the former is what we use to construct software which can be used in simulating the latter.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is a bit confusing what you're trying to do here, but I'll take a stab at this.

First up you are really abusing `StringBuilder`. It's not necessary for your code in this situation and you're just making things more complicated than necessary.

Here's your first code example without `StringBuilder`:

```
for (int h = 0; h < aminoAcidCodons[0].Multiplicity; h++)
{
    codonsList0.Add(aminoAcidCodons[0].Codons[h]);
    for (int j = 0; j < aminoAcidCodons[1].Multiplicity; j++)
    {
        codonsList1.Add(
            aminoAcidCodons[0].Codons[h]
            + aminoAcidCodons[1].Codons[j]);
    }
}
```

Much simpler!

Now for the generalised version:

```
private IEnumerable<string> CombineCodons(
    AminoAcidCodon[] aminoAcidCodons,
    int index)
{
    for (int h = 0; h < aminoAcidCodons[index].Multiplicity; h++)
    {
        yield return aminoAcidCodons[index].Codons[h];
        if (index + 1 < aminoAcidCodons.Length)
        {
            foreach (var child in CombineCodons(aminoAcidCodons, index + 1))
            {
                yield return aminoAcidCodons[index].Codons[h] + child;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I think this is close.

Call it this way:

```
codonsList1.AddRange(CombineCodons(aminoAcidCodons, 0));
```

Comment: thanks to be on the same page : aminoAcidCodons is a list of AminoAcidCodon objects   : class AminoAcidCodon {  int Multiplicity {get; set;} Boolean Stop{}; string AminoAcid{}; List<string> Codons{};      }..........I have a table of genetic code from which I populated ...continue

Comment: from which I populated aminoAcidCodons list  for peptide say MW and it contains   two objects of AminoAcidCodon  like this: {Multiplicity=1, Stop=false, AminoAcid="M", Codons={"AUG"}}  and a second similar one for W with AminoAcid="W",Codons={"UGG}

Comment: You still need to explain how that generalisation works.

Comment: it is not working! I am trying this pseudo code    for i=0 to codonsListcount    get codonsi    for j=1 to codonsList-1

Comment: @kobosh - What's not working? It looks like your comment was cut short.